# What is RzKLService.exe?

Tags: windows, virus

So... I installed Java (I know its unsafe) because I need to use some installers that require Java Runtime. Also, after searching for a program that could do something to me, I saw a site, I clicked on it and chrome saved me by saying that this site contains malicious software.

The point is, I saw that `RzKLService.exe` running in the background, while I was checking those applications just to make sure that I didn't install anything bad. What is this RZKLService exactly? Are they simply some kind of drivers? After Googling this I saw unclear answers talking about trojans but I don't know

[image: Task Manager screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a service used by [Razer Game Booster](http://www.razerzone.com/cortex/game-booster).

Legitimate software and nothing to worry about, assuming it's in the correct folder location, I believe `C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\Razer Cortex\RzKLService.exe`. If it's located in a folder like your documents or roaming app data, it's likely not legitimate.

You can use these steps to find out where it's running from:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> -> `services.msc`
2. Look for `Razer` in the list, `Right Click` and click `Properties`

Here it should tell you the file path under `Path to executable`.

Comment: I have Razer Game Booster, and with the Rz starting I thought it was Razer but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

#### I saw that RzKLService.exe running in the background

> , while I was checking those applications just to make sure that I didn't install anything bad.

[Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) (a Task Manager replacement) allows you to:

1. See the exact command line used to launch a process by hovering over the process name):

   [image]

   - This allows you to check if a program is being launched from an unusual location.
2. Send appropriate details about a running program to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) (and optionally two other virus check websites):

   [image]

   - Right click program name > Select "Send To" > select "virustotal.com"
   - This will check if the program is know to be a virus, worm, trojan, or other type of malware.

Note:

- Above images use firefox.exe for illustration as I don't have RzKLService.exe installed.

---

#### Process Hacker

> A free, powerful, multi-purpose tool that helps you monitor system resources,
>   debug software and detect malware.
>
> Process Hacker is open source and can be modified or redistributed.

Source [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Comment: The link you sent me is from Sourceforge, and their installer is trying to sell me stuff, and as what I have heard they might ask me to download Malware too. Is there a different mirror? Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, was this actual windows 199x or you used the theme of it?

Comment: Windows 7 classic theme.

Comment: Use the portable version (no install required) http://wj32.org/processhacker/rel/processhacker-2.36-bin.zip